# luatex node library: restore pdf transformation matrix to original state after adding pdf_setmatrix node

Tags: luatex, pdf, transformation

How can I restore back to the original pdf transformation matrix after changing it using pdf_setmatrix whatsit node? The restore node should work with vlist/hlist/word/glyph. Below is the complete code from my attempt to apply pdf transformation matrix only to line number 3 of paragraph, screenshot of unintended behavior (seems like transformation got applied to all lines from line number 3 onwards, correct solution will restore pdf transformation matrix back to its original state at end of line number 3) and the image from [PDF 1.7 reference manual](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

*Note: The pdf transformations I am talking about are explained in section 8.3 of [PDF 1.7 reference manual](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), with examples on page 118, 119 in figure 13, and figure 14; and concept of pdf transformation matrix explained in section 8.3.4.*

Output from my attempt:
[image: my broken output]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2in,right=2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\directlua{
    function my_post_lb_filter(head,groupcode)
      local linenumber=1;
      local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
      local WHATSIT = node.id("whatsit")
      for n in node.traverse(head) do
        if n.id==HLIST then
          if linenumber==3 then
            local matrix = node.new(WHATSIT,"pdf_setmatrix");
            matrix.data = "1 0 0 1 1 0";
            n.head=node.insert_before(n.list,n.head,matrix);
            % NOTE: Append node to the end of n.list to restore the state pdf matrix back to original (the way it was supposed to be before I appended node matrix at the beginning of line)
          end
        linenumber=linenumber+1;
        end
      end
      return head
    end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', my_post_lb_filter, 'Play with luatex node library')
}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Screenshot from PDF 1.7 manual:

[image: current transformation matrix]

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Did you try to insert a pdf.restore? And if yes, what went wrong?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After posting my question, I searched the web more. This was the problem: pdfsave and pdfrestore need to be at exact position in the pdf. Which means that before applying pdfrestore one needs to add a kern node to move back to the exact same position on the pdf page where pdfsave was added. This is as per Heiko Oberdiek on this thread: https://luatex.tug.narkive.com/E1GaOOE9/luatex-warning-misplaced-pdfrestore-by-983040sp-0sp That solves the problem.